# Bitset split into chars

Tags: c++, bitset

I have a quite big bitset:

```
bitset<128*8> bs;
```

i would like to have access to groups of 8 bits.
What of though of so far:

1. bs.to_string()
2. split into a vector of string of size 8
3. create a new bitset from these strings and call to_ulong()

Is there a better solution? Performance is crucial, since i call this method multiple times in my program.

Comment: After some rudimentary googling, I'd suggest to write an own wrapper class (possibly derived from `bitset`), that supports char-wise access.

Comment: Almost sounds like you want a `char[]` (or `std::array<char>`).

Comment: `std::vector<unsigned char>(128)` ?

Comment: i use the type as a key, so i need to use a hashable type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/operator_ltltgtgt) has operator `>>`.

If you want just access to the value and read it, you can use below code. It reads N *th* 8 bit as a `uint8_t`:

```
bitset<128*8> mask(0xFF);
uint8_t x = ((bs >> N * 8) & mask).to_ulong();
```

Comment: to_ulong throws a overflow exception if bitset cannot be expressed in a unsigned long.

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski: Umm, how about this updated version :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this to avoid creating strings and some copying:

```
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < bs.size(); i+=8) {
    uint32_t uval = 0;
    for (uint32_t j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        uval = (uval << 1) + bs[i + 7 - j]; 
    }   
    std::cout << uval << std::endl;
}
```

but you may need to work on the indices depending on your endianness